# Does anyone have considerable proof that CHAR is faster than VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, char, varchar, benchmarking

Any benchmark, graph anything at all ? Its all academic and theoretical across the web.

Ok its not the first time that this question has been asked, they all say that using CHAR results in faster selects? I even read in MySQL books, its all the same but I have not come across any benchmark that proves this.

Can any one shed some light over this?

Comment: It's not, unless you have fixed length strings, then char is faster.

Comment: No wait, then by nature CHAR cannot have variable sting length, as the rest is a part of the string only that its just white space, I dont think the "unless" part would apply here as its already fixed. –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple logic, to simplify I'll take the example of a CSV file...

would it be faster to search in this line

1231;231;32345;21312;23435552;1231;1;243;211;3525321;44343112;

or this one

12;23;43;54;56;76;54;83;45;91;28;92

as long as you define your length correctly CHAR should be faster as the predefined format help the processing time.

Comment: So if what you are saying is true, there is no real speed increase in using CHAR unless, for example a "fullname CHAR(20)" column has all the full names exactly filled with relevant data to 20 chars. Right? or that happens automatically because dead space is added as a trail on these columns?

Comment: Space is added -- so it's always exactly 20.  That's why it's faster.

Comment: Note that this only applies if ALL fields in the row are fixed-width.

Comment: To make the example accurate when you have variable length strings you would have to represent a lot of blank characters for the char. In which case, the varchar is actually easier to read.

Comment: We have a wonderful contradiction again :)"In which case, the varchar is actually easier to read."

Answer (score 5):

The point is, it is not. Not by itself anyway.

What is true however, is that if there are **only** fixed width fields in the table, MySQL does not need to perform some calculations to find out the beginnings of each field.

Also there might be a difference for very short fields. If you compare CHAR(1) vs VARCHAR(1), the latter takes twice as much memory as the first (in single byte encodings)

Answer (score 0):

CHAR will be faster as it is fixed length.
For example CHAR(10) and VARCHAR(10)
CHAR(10) is a fixed-length string of 10 while VARCHAR is a variable-length string with maximum length of 10.

**VARCHAR(10)**

```
 {Index} (Length) [String]
 -------------------------
 {0} (8) [AAAAAAAA]
 {1} (5) [BBBBB]
 {2} (3) [CCC]
 {3} (7) [DDDDDDD]
 {4} (2) [EE]
 {5} (4) [FFFF]
```

**CHAR(10)**

```
 {Index} (Length) [String]
 -------------------------
 {0} (10) [AAAAAAAA  ]
 {1} (10) [BBBBB     ]
 {2} (10) [CCC       ]
 {3} (10) [DDDDDDD   ]
 {4} (10) [EE        ]
 {5} (10) [FFFF      ]
```

So imagine you have a table with 1,000,000 records and you need to get a record at offset 500,000.

**CHAR** - database engine would have to do multiply **500,000 x 10** = offset is 5,000,000.

**VARCHAR** - database engine would have to get each row length and sum them all **5 + 8 + 9 + 3 + 2 + 4...** 500,000 times to get offset

CHAR padding is x00 which basically is end of the string so
**CHAR(10) = [A,A,A,A,A,00,00,00,00,00]** is **"AAAAA"**.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should pick up the glove and just do it.