# Is there any point in using CHAR if you have a VARCHAR in the same table?

Tags: mysql, performance, char, varchar

I just read the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262238/are-there-disadvantages-to-using-a-generic-varchar255-for-all-text-based-fields), which left me with this question.

Here's a quote from that answer:

"But since you tagged this question with MySQL, I'll mention a MySQL-specific tip:  when your query implicitly generates a temporary table, for instance while sorting or `GROUP BY`, `VARCHAR` fields are converted to `CHAR` to gain the advantage of working with fixed-width rows.  If you use a lot of `VARCHAR(255)` fields for data that doesn't need to be that long, this can make the temporary table very large."

As I understand it, the advantage of `CHAR` is that you get fixed-width rows, so doesn't a `VARCHAR` in the same table mess that up? Are there any advantages of using `CHAR` when you have a `VARCHAR` in the same table?

---

Here's an example:

Table with `CHAR`:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    postcode CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Table without `CHAR`:

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    street VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    postcode VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Will the table with `CHAR` perform any better than the table without `CHAR`, and if so, in what situations?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408930/does-anyone-have-considerable-proof-that-char-is-faster-than-varchar

Comment: The `char` table will use less space, because it doesn't have an extra field for "length of the postcode string" in every record.

Comment: @Slomojo: That question is about whether there is any advantages of `CHAR` at all and that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @Anon: I don't really care about that byte, but it's a valid point.

Comment: Regardless, CHAR(8) is a better description of the data than VARCHAR(8).

Comment: In SQL Server one advantage of `char` is for updates. If a field gets updated to a longer value the row may not fit where it was meaning a forwarding pointer needs to be used (for a heap) or a page split in a clustered index. I guess similar considerations may well apply in MySQL as well but don't know enough about the storage implementation to offer a definitive answer.

Comment: I guess char followed by varchar will make some difference than the varchar followed by char as shown in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`VARCHAR`" basically sets a maximum length for the field and only stores the data that is entered into it, thus saving on space. The "`CHAR`" type has a fixed length, so if you set "`CHAR(100)`", 100 character worth of space will be used regardless of what the contents are.

The only time you will gain a speed advantage is if you have no variable length fields in your record ("`VARCHAR`", "`TEXT`", etc.). <strike>You may notice that</strike> Internally all your "`CHAR`" fields are changed to "`VARCHAR`" as soon as a variable length field type is added, by MySQL.

Also "`CHAR`" is less efficient from a space storage point of view, but more efficient for searching and adding. It's faster because the database only has to read an offset value to get a record rather than reading parts until it finds the end of a record. And fixed length records will minimize fragmentation, since deleted record space can be reused for new records.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you saying that postcode will be treated as a `VARCHAR` just because street is a `VARCHAR`? Will this just happen internally or will MySQL tell me that my `CHAR` field now is a `VARCHAR` field?

Comment: @Erik - It will happen internally. Edited the answer.

Comment: I don't have any actual proof that what you're saying is true, but it's upvoted, it makes sense and no one has opposed, so I'll accept it as my answer.